# CascadeType.ALL error when using FetchType.EAGER

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I have this situation (using springMVC + hibernate):

One "PriceList" record is made by one "Service" and one "Company":

PriceList Class:

```
//Many to one with Company
@NotNull(message = "....")  
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
private Company company;


//Many to one with Service
@NotNull(message = "....")  
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "service_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
private Service service;
```

Service Class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="service", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
private Set<PriceList> priceList;
```

Company Class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="company", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
private Set<Company> company;
```

My problem is when i try to DELETE a PriceList:
without EAGER everything is fine,
but with if i keep CascadeType.ALL and FetchType.EAGER i get this error:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: deleted
>   object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from
>   associations): 
>   nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: **deleted object would be re-saved
>   by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)**

I don't understand why i get this error... i don't think there are any problems if i want to remove  a "priceList" record.

I think that i should flush or something like this before delete my record...

I i remove a Company or a Service, everything is fine because also records in PriceList are removed.

Thank you very much for any suggestion

Comment: As far as i have tested, hibernate seems not to support the FetchType of the standard jpa. remove it, and use LazyCollection(FALSE) instead

Comment: Thank you @maress, but honestly i can't say if i'm using JPA or Hibernate .. I'm very new to java / spring / hibernate world and i'm learning day by day building this project. btw i think i found a good solution (answer below): remove object from the Company Set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with bidirectional associations and you want to add/remove children you should have these methods in your Parent entity:

```
public void addChild(Child child) {
    children.add(child);
    child.setParent(this);
}

public void removeChild(Child child) {
    children.remove(child);
    child.setParent(null);
}
```

The remove will break both the parent/child and the child/parent associations.

Comment: thanks. are these method mandatory ? (for example like getter and setter). i ask because on tutorial i used for building this project, i never seen this

Answer (score 0):

I found that, before delete PriceList record, i have to remove it from the PriceList collection in Company (because using EAGER loads in memory all PriceList):

```
priceList_removing.getCompany().getPriceLists().remove(priceList_removing);

getCurrentSession().delete(priceList_removing);
```

Comment: btw this can be ok for a simple relation like this. but if i add a third relation to PriceList, for example Seller, when i have to remember to remove priceList from Company before remove Seller... i think it's hard to keep in mind and easy to forgot put this remove(priceList_removing) in every entity involved